# Why does flutter web show special characters are displayed instead of text?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

My flutter web page is displaying ▯▯▯▯ instead of text?  What can be the issue?
The numbers are showing fine

Comment: Maybe you don't have the correct font in the machine..?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this!

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html or --web-renderer canvaskit
```